# The property wrap_content is not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-wrap-content

I have to make a TextView horizontal inside a LinearLayout and vertical inside a ConstraintLayout.
The problem is that the property `wrap_content` of the TextView is not working.
This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.black_swan.myapplication11.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the image of the project:

[image: here the image of design]

Comment: Stop using the nested LinearLayout or remove the layout_weight

Comment: without nested linerlayout the wrap content work fine , But why it not work with nested linerlayout @cricket_007

Comment: Because the layout_weight is overriding the wrap_content

Comment: ok , clear thanks @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:layout_weight="1"` on `TextView`. Further more It seems that your `TextView's` parent `LinearLayout` is not useful. Try not using unnecessary nested layouts.

Comment: it work when I remove android:layout_weight="1" on TextView , thank you ... I will accept your answer after 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you use a layout weight, typically, you would use a size of `0dp` for the corresponding direction.

- 0dp width for horizontal
- 0dp height for vertical

When you use the weight, then wrap_content size is overridden